# What does improving a function's running time mean?

Tags: algorithm, performance, function, big-o

Suppose a function has a total of 10N + 10 steps. The function class would just be O(N) then. If I want to improve the function's running time, does that mean decrease the number of steps and reduce the function class so that it's less than linear?

Comment: I don't think there exists any formal definition. IMO it's either. Run-time is run-time, i'd interpret it as wall clock. Going 10N+0 might give you 10 seconds or 10 minutes (totally made up numbers). Going 5N will halve the run-time. Going `ln N` probably even more, but it's all improved run-time. Whether it's significant or not is another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally you are reducing a function's running time if you make it runs in shorter time. Normally there are two direction to do this: Imagine real life running, you can run in shorter time by strengthen your muscles (upgrade to NASA super computer), or by shorten the distance that you have to run (Improve / change the algorithm to reduce the steps). We only focus the second direction.

---

Still there are tons of factor to consider like what is the realistic input to your function?

If **N is small** 99% of the time, then **constant factor matters** even they are of same class O(N).
O(10^6*N) and O(2*N) are both O(N), but N is not that dominant when it is smaller than 10^6

If **N is** usually **large**, you can still say you have improved the function by reducing the constant factor, but it is negligible (but yes you are still reducing it). If you need an observable boost, then you may need to **change the algorithm, change the data structures**, in order to improve the function to a better complexity class (from O(N) to O(lg N) for example).

---

Therefore, using your own words: *"decrease the number of steps"* and *"reduce the function class"* are both reducing the running time of the function, but which one is observable and thus useful, depends on its usage and other realistic factors.